# AngularJS - Multiple expression aliases

Tags: angularjs

If I have two filters, I'd like to display the length of both in the results (one without the limit, one with the limit), but I can only create one alias... so this does not work:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:user_search_string as unlimited_users | limitTo:12 as limited_users">{{user.name}}</div>
<div>{{ limited_users }} of {{ unlimited_users }} matches displayed</div>
```

I'd like it to say ... "12 of 34 matches displayed" but I am not sure how.

Comment: you can use `ng-init` to create variables and use them as aliases: `<div ng-init="foo = baz | filtered"></div>` but keep in mind that you should use only simple expressions on your view, how to structure view data and view business logic is a controller concern.

Comment: use the .length property: {{unlimited_users.length}}